# How do I move an Image in a Canvas without making it bound to the outer Grid it belongs to?

Tags: c#, wpf, image, canvas, grid

I want to place an Image on the top of a certain tile in a tile based game I am making. Problem is, when I generate the random map, when the Rectangle children of the Canvas is drawn, it draws over the Image. I solved this issue by placing making the Image part of the outer Grid of the Window. Problem is that when I want to place the Image on a certain Rectangle within the Canvas, the co-ordinates are off since the Grid is larger than the Canvas. How can I limit the Image Margins to only that of the Canvas (the canvas borders as the limit) as opposed to the Grid borders as the limits?

E.g. Giving the Image a value of Margin.Left = 50 will place it in the perfect spot in the canvas, but it would be placed on a different location in the grid since its scale is larger.

```
// Image displays, but does not display when I add child Rectangles to the Canvas
<Canvas Height="700" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700">
        <Image Name="heroImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="hero.png" Height="74" Canvas.Left="558" Canvas.Top="602" />
</Canvas>



<Grid>
    <Canvas Height="700" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700">
        // Removed the Image
    </Canvas>

    // Placed the Image outside the Canvas, but now it will draw according to the Grid's Margin limits and not the Canvas Margin limits
    <Image Name="heroImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="hero.png" Height="74" Canvas.Left="558" Canvas.Top="602" />
</Grid>
```

[image: Image position inside Canvas]
Image inside the Canvas, perfectly positioned

[image: Image position outside the Canvas in the Grid]
Image in the grid, wrongly placed since I used Canvas Margin co-ordinates

Comment: Post a screenshot. Your explanation is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

The first way you did it was good, your image should be a child of your Canvas to do Canvas.Left...

To solve you problem can you just put your image on top of all other rectangle, with ZIndex?

```
Canvas.ZIndex="3 or whatever"
```

The image with value 2 is drawn over the Rectangle with value 1. So you can pu a high number...

Answer (score 1):

I think that you could use your image inside the Canvas and if you want the image over the Rectangle, the you need set the image's (Palen.ZIndex or Canvas.ZIndex) property greater than the Rectangles one.
For instance:

```
<Canvas Height="700" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="700">
        <Image Name="heroImage" Stretch="Fill" Source="hero.png" Height="74" Canvas.Left="558" Canvas.Top="602" Canvas.ZIndex="1000" />
        <Rectangle x:Name="Some Rectangle" Canvas.ZIndex="1"/>
</Canvas>
```

The image will be showed over the rectangle. I think this is the solution. Putting the image out the canvas cause will be very complex to set the exactly position you want.

Comment: This is what i wrote 5 minutes ago, so if we both think that I think it's the best way

Comment: Yes, I have a slow connection, so when I write the answer, I didn't see yours, certanly that is the solution. :) Hope this works for mlemay.